# IntelliJ IDE optimizing "out" important imports

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I've been using JetBrains IntelliJ since around 2006. I love the IDE. In the past 6 month the latest version frequently optimizes "out" imports from my JSPs that are needed. It might be my fault but I make frequent use of ".inc" files to includes headers and other includes for standard functionality across my web application.

I have searched and made a help request of the folks at JetBrains - nothing.

Is this happening to anyone else?

A standard Java file works fine - I turned off optimize imports so it shows me the "dimmed" version of imports and I have the choice of removing them manually.

It is still REMOVING them from my .inc files that I import into my .jsp files. I have .inc setup to validate syntax as .jsp- but with optimize imports off it is frustrating to deploy an application where a very base class import is missing. I have even taking measure to use methods such as

`Class _______forceImportThisClass = ThisClass.class;`

The syntax validation doesn't even complain about the missing import for "ThisClass". I don't think the correct option is to stop using include files. And I've used this feature for about 7 years. I'm wondering if anyone else is experiencing the same problem and has found a fix.

Comment: Of import - under Preferences, File Types/Java Server Page files I added *.inc to the list. This was the strategy I used in the past to ensure the page had the necessary imports.

Comment: More info - I know the import is an issue b/c Apache Tomcat tries to compile the page. Upon opening the page and MANUALLY adding the import to the .inc file - this is fixable. Just to be clear, I want to resolve the issue of the imports being optimized "out" when they are clearly required.

Comment: Importing "urchin" code from for Google tracking for example. I certainly don't want Java code using out.println() for tracking code. However, it may need something like <code><%=pageTitle%></code> to pass to Google.

Comment: That's why I've removed all my comments.  I'll let you find an answer without my pedanticism! Good luck.

Comment: @jahroy - Do you use IntelliJ? I'm a fan. The IDE just changes from time to time and you have to figure out how to work around the new issues. This isn't a problem that I cannot resolve - but it is frustrating to have a ".jsp" file open and have the IDE think all the classes you are using are fine and you look at the import section and know it won't really compile. Again, FAN of the IDE, just looking for solutions.

Comment: I've used IntelliJ very little, but I definitely understand how frustrating it is when IDEs try too hard t\o "_help_" you.

Comment: @jahroy Good tool for Java and a few other languages. LOL. Looked at your profile. Really?? Capitalization in Java? Good answer - don't they have schools or books that teach that? EDIT - been programming since 1983 so Java was something I had to accept.

Comment: I love/hate every IDE I've tried!  Java was created while I was in school, but I actually enjoy it (for the most part).  Re: capitalization - kids ask the darndest things on this site!

Comment: I got that 1996 Duke thing going. Been through all the changes. SO is a good site - used to use experts exchange but I think some information should be collaborative and shared by tech folks.

Comment: LOL Duke was the original Java mascot's name...